# 2 activities - A launches B - sometimes destroy A before restarting it from B?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I tried this code in activity B to start A anew :

```
intent.setFlags(IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
SettingsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);    
finish();
```

Then onBackPressed() calls for an alertDialog that call : `clearBackStack();` set a flag and call `onBackPressed()` again that directly launches `super.onBackPressed();` because of the flag.

It looks like the `super.onBackPressed()` sends me to an old task where the activity A was.

What should I do to restart A from B (only in some cases, so noHistory won't do) and with API 8 compat?

Edit : I don't want to restart A anew when the user just press back or Up. I want to restart A when the application receives a message telling it to update. My mistake was having the call for updating in the `onCreate()` method that is NOT performed when going back in the stack. I now put it in `onStart()`.

I initially put it in `onCreate()` to **start as soon as possible the connection with the server** because the drawing of the layout took some time; now, when the user will start the appli, this call will execute a tiny bit later. Do you have comments, suggestions, relevant links on how to better solve this ?

Edit 2 : Forget about the "some time", I forgot I had optimized and put asynchronous stuff and now i only need 150 - 200 ms to reach the end of the onResume(); thus the delay is negligible in front of networking connection delays. Solved.

Comment: "only in some cases" - what cases? When do you want to start A anew, and when you don't want?

Comment: You should delete this question. It is misleading and will cause others to get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at activity lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html). Basically, when you start an activity, the callback methods are called in specific order - see the diagram:

[image]

So onCreate() will only be called if your activity has been destroyed, and as you noticed, when moving back in stack, onStart() was being called.

Also, it would be a good idea to move intensive tasks (such as connecting to your server) into a separate thread - don't do it on UI thread.

There are several ways to do this, please see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable.html).

For example, you can use AsyncTask:

> To use it, you must subclass AsyncTask and implement the doInBackground() callback method, which runs in a pool of background threads. To update your UI, you should implement onPostExecute(), which delivers the result from doInBackground() and runs in the UI thread, so you can safely update your UI. You can then run the task by calling execute() from the UI thread.

Sample code from the docs:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://example.com/image.png");
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    /** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
      * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
    }

    /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
      * the result from doInBackground() */
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but I already know or did all that as I said in my Edits :) 
I can say I solve my issue with a better organization of the methods, but my direct question still stands, **for curiosity** : how to force an activity to restart from another one ?